# I can not like facebook post in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala-gem

I want to like a facebook post in my rails application but I get the error:

`Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 200, message: (#200) Permissions error [HTTP 403]`

my omniauth file includes:

`provider :facebook_writer, ENV['facebook_writer_key'], ENV['facebook_writer_secret'], info_fields: 'friends', scope: 'publish_actions, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_stream'`

Items in my facebook application are not approved yet.

Any clue why this is happening? Do I need to be approved?

Answer (score 0):

I added

`client_options: {
   site: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0'
 }`

to my provider